# "IntervalPicker": Customizing datePicker or developing own control?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone, silverlight-toolkit

This is more of a principal question, than one with a specific source code problem. I hope this is okay.

I am developing an application for Windows Phone and want to have a control that looks like a [Silverlight-Toolkit](https://phone.codeplex.com/) [DatePicker](https://phone.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/80797#1335967) but instead of selecting day/month/year, I'd like to select an recurrence-interval with the following layout:

```
   .        ..
   1       Days
 -----    ---------
|  2  |  | Weeks   |
 -----    ---------
   3       Months
   .        ..
```

One field at the left side, where you can select a number, and a field at the right that gives that number a "unit".

Of course I could just use a text-input field and list, but having this "intervalPicker" would look somewhat nicer and fit more into the overall input scheme (I am using an datePicker and timePicker control to set the starting point of the reoccurring event).

I am fairly new to this whole XAML-world, as I'm just setting foot in it.
My question would be if you could provide me hints, which solution would be most feasible.

- Develop my own control (a lot of work to get it right, I assume)
- "Enhance" datePicker
- Take the date/timePicker code from the Silverlight-Toolkit and customize it.
- Use an already available control, that I just haven't found yet.
- ?

I am fretting which solution would be best, but as I am fairly inexperienced in this regard, I'd like to do it "the most conforming" way possible and for that I'd love to have your experienced input on this (maybe it is (fairly) easily possible to "subclass" the base-picker-control in way that I can do this?)

I am looking forward to hearing your suggestions and insights.

P.S.: I wanted to tag my question as `windows-phone-toolkit` since the [Silverlight Toolkit](https://silverlight.codeplex.com/) for Windows Phone has been renamed to "Windows Phone Toolkit". Unfortunately the tag didn't exist yet and my reputation was to low to create it. It would be nice, if a higher ranked user could create that tag. I think that future questions could use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest looking at the [Timespan Picker in the Coding4Fun Tools for Windows Phone](http://coding4fun.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=TimeSpanPicker&referringTitle=Documentation). I don't see the option for the Days/Weeks/Months slider, but I'm sure if you started with their control you could add that in pretty easily.

Comment: Looks good! I'll try it out within the next days and see if it fits

Answer (score 0):

Just stick two of these together and style accordingly https://github.com/buymeasoda/jquery-option-picker

Comment: Sorry, but I don't see how your answer applies to my problem-domain :|. I edited my question and clarified that I want to develop a control for a WindowsPhone application.

Comment: @lx. bah my bad, had another question (about javascript and html) open at the same time. Must have gotten confused!